# .Net 5.0 Web API deployment issue on IIS

Tags: c#, iis, .net-core

I am having issues with .net core web api deployments on IIS.

- I have created the simple web api project using .net core 5. This opens up correctly while running through VS 2019.
- I have installed the .net core 5.0.2 hosting bundle on my machine. [image]
- Created the application pool with the "No Managed Code" settings.[image]
- Published the API using vs folder published and created the IIS site that points to the published folder.

After following all these required steps i am not able to browse through the published APIs using localhost. but it shows some weird errors like HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found

[image]

Comment: What is the url of the API you are trying to connect?

Comment: There is no net core 5. It is just Net 5.0

Comment: How do you access localhost? Have you set the default document? How do you publish your application? Please post error page about your issue.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya Its default weather forecast endpoint.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure the necessary feature like static content and asp.net feature in turn windows  features on or off/add role and feature->internet information service->world wide web service->application development feature->asp.net has been enabled.

In addition, you could try to add **runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"** attribute to your module section just like:

```
<system.webServer>
  <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" >    
  </modules>
</system.webServer>
```

Or you could try

```
<system.webServer>
 <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" >
   <remove name="UrlRoutingModule"/>    
 </modules>
</system.webServer>
```